# spyne generating invalid schema

Tags: lxml, spyne

I am trying to use spyne from master branch as the released versions are not compatible with python3 and I have models defined like these:

```
class currency(ComplexModel):                                                   
    data = XmlData(Decimal)                                                     


class mntCurrency(currency):                                                    
    code = XmlAttribute(String)                                                 


class CreditLmt(ComplexModel):                                                  
    curr = mntCurrency
```

I have plugged these models into a simple HelloWorld Service which returns CreditLmt in response. But when I try to run my soap server, spyne complains with the following:

> lxml.etree.XMLSchemaParseError: Element
>   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}extension': The content is not
>   valid. Expected is (annotation?, ((group | all | choice | sequence)?,
>   ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?)))., line 16

Which is correct because spyne generates the following xsd:

```
 <xs:complexType name="mntCurrency">                                           
    <xs:complexContent>                                                         
      <xs:extension base="tns:currency">                                        
        <xs:simpleContent>                                                      
          <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">                                      
            <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string"/>                        
          </xs:extension>                                                       
        </xs:simpleContent>                                                     
        <xs:sequence>                                                           
          <xs:element name="test" type="xs:token" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
        </xs:sequence>                                                          
      </xs:extension>                                                           
    </xs:complexContent>                                                        
  </xs:complexType>
```

I am using XmlData because I want to have reponse such that it looks like this:

```
<tns:currency code="826">10.0</tns:currency>
```

So how do I define my models?

Answer (score 0):

An example for generating this element:

```xml
<tns:currency code="826">10.0</tns:currency>
```

... is as follows:

```py
from spyne import *
from spyne.util.xml import get_object_as_xml

from lxml import etree


class Currency(ComplexModel):
    value = XmlData(Decimal)
    code = XmlAttribute(Integer32(values=[826, 234, 555]))


class SomeObject(ComplexModel):
    handle = Unicode
    currency = Currency


obj = SomeObject(handle="aaaa", currency=Currency(value=D('123.45'), code=555))
elt = get_object_as_xml(obj)
print(etree.tostring(elt, pretty_print=True))
```

As for the error, it is coming directly from libxml. It is essentially saying that the Xml Schema standard doesn't allow lone `XmlData` entries in a ComplexModel subclass. If you think this is an error, you must complain to the Xml Schema working group.